# aws-sdk s3.getObject with redirect

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In short, I'm trying to resize an image through through a redirect, aws lambda, and the aws-sdk.

Following along the tutorial on resizing an image on the fly with AWS, [AWS - resize-images-on-the-fly](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/), I've managed to make everything work according to the walkthrough, however my question is related to making the call to the bucket.

Currently the only way I can get this to work is by calling,
`http://MY_BUCKET_WEBSITE_HOSTNAME/25×25/blue_marble.jpg`.

If the image isn't available, the request is redirected, image resized, and then placed back in the bucket.

What I would like to do, is access the bucket in the aws-sdk through the s3.getObject() call, rather than to that direct link.

As of now, I can only access the images that are currently in the bucket, so the redirect is never happening.

My thought was the request wasn't being sent to the correct endpoint and from what I was able to find online, I changed the way the sdk was created to this -

`s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: "myAccessKeyId",
  secretAccessKey: "mySecretAccessKey",
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: '<MYBUCKET>.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  s3BucketEndpoint: true,
  sslEnabled: false,
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
})
params = {
  Bucket: 'MY_BUCKET',
  Key: '85x85/blue_marble.jpg'
};
s3.getObject(params, (error, data) => data);`

From what I can tell the endpoints in the request look correct.
[image: request endpoints]

When I visit the endpoints directly in the browser, everything works as expected.

But when using the sdk, only available images return. There is no redirect, no data returns, and I get the error.

> XMLParserError: Non-whitespace before first tag.

Not sure if it's possible to do with s3.getObject(), seems like it may, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The endpoints with the SDK can be changed, as you found, but it isn't designed to work with the web site endpoints, hence the XML error.  The web site endpoints also don't support credentials-based access -- they are only for public content.  Why are you trying to use the SDK instead of just a normal HTTP request?

Comment: Mostly have been trying to familiarize myself in working with the SDK. It seemed like it could work, but it wasn't and wanted to know why.

Never found something specifically stating the SDK isn't designed to work with the website endpoints like that. Which is why I was hoping to ask someone with more knowledge before moving forward. Thanks!

Comment: See also [Key Differences Between the Amazon Website and the REST API Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff).

Answer (score 0):

Use headObject to check if the object exists. If not you can call your API to do the resize & then retry the get after the resize.

```
var params = {
    Bucket: config.get('s3bucket'),
    Key: path
};

s3.headObject(params, function (err, metadata) {  
  if (err && err.code === 'NotFound') {  
    // Call your resize API here. Once your resize API returns a success, you can get the object\URL.
  } else {  
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, callback); //Use this secure URL to access the object.
 }
});
```

Comment: Hoping there is a way for everything to be handled by a single s3.getSignedUrl or s3.getObject call.

Not that this doesn't work... Just looking for a way to call getObject which hits the 404 redirect and sends me back the file as an array buffer. 

Which may not even be possible. Any idea if something like that works? Otherwise your solution did get me where I needed to be.

Comment: That is not possible as far as I know.